# Where can I ask if people are proud of former colonies in GB?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Great Britain had lot of colonies. The colonies were ripped of. Rebels were killed and inhabitants enslaved.

I want to know if people in GB are proud of former colonies or if they judge it.

Comment: If there is any site (and I'm not aware of one), it would probably help your post tremendously if you have more than just 'your impression', but e.g. some news articles (from renowned news papers) that actually demonstrate this attitude.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I edited my question. Now I want to know if people are proud. I am no longer saying they are. Where to ask this question?

Comment: As a survey on your blog?

Comment: There is the matter of question form. For the same information, it could be about whether some ([humanities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanities)) researchers have done an investigation, survey, or interviews on this matter, and what the results were. That may or may not still be off-topic, incl. depending on how it is posed. For instance, you may be expected to do some research first.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We prefer to answer questions with facts. Whether that is source code that does compile or paragraphs of law or rules from a rulebook or sourced quotes from people's factual statements.

What you are asking for is an opinion poll. We do not do this here.

If you want to break up your question in multiple factual questions, you could look for sites answering *those*.

An example might be "What was the British governments official standpoint concerning the Indian rebellion of 1857?". You could ask that on History.SE. Or even "What is the current British governments position on the Indian rebellion of 1857?". That might be on topic for politics. You would need to make sure that you have exhausted your other obvious sources on the matter, like Wikipedia pages and Google searches though. Otherwise it will probably get closed as "lacks research" on both sites.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to nvoigt's answer - I feel like many aspects of the question fit under the sort of question [we don't want people to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Specifically -

> every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

There are many reasons someone might be proud of parts of their history, and many ways to look at it.  There are many possible valid answers.

> there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”

Its an attempt to find validation for a point of view rather than solving a problem or finding a definitive answer to a question.

The answer could also change over time depending on how folks see their own history. Fundamentally a question with no one right answer isn't a great fit here.